# php - set a default value on a dropdown selector from db

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a dropdown menu on my view that lets me select different items from the table. But, since by default there is one possible option at this instance, I want to set it instead of manually changing each one.

This is the code:

```
<td><?php   
        $tabindex = 1;          
        $extras = 'class = "smallInput" tabindex='.$tabindex;
        $tracking_status_array = array ();
        $tracking_status_array += array ('' => 'Select Status' );
        foreach ( $tracking_status_list as $status ) {
          $tracking_status_array += array (trim ( $status->tracking_status_id ) =>  trim ( $status->status_text )  );
        }
        echo form_dropdown ( 'tracking_status_id[]', $tracking_status_array, set_value ( 'tracking_status_id[]'), $extras);
        ?></td>
```

Comment: How is `form_dropdown` defined? It looks like it accepts an array of options and builds the dropdown menu. Maybe just send an array of one?

Comment: I dont want to remove the rest of the values because maybe in the future i might need one of those others, i only want to set one as default instead of blank as default

Comment: How do you expect us to discern how the default is set without knowing what `form_dropdown` is? Are you using a particular framework you can link to? Is that custom code?

Comment: nevermind, i figured out, i comment out this line

    $tracking_status_array += array ('' => 'Select Status' );

and now the default value is the first value of the array, which happens to be the one i needed!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to remove the rest of the values because maybe in the future i might need one of those others, i only want to set one as default instead of blank as default